# Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: error while trying to connect to local router at address

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory is not accessible after an upgrade from 7.38.7 to 7.71.8 or any higher version. I am seeing the following error in the console log.

===============================================================================================
Cluster join: Retry 280: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp [::1]:8046: connect: connection refused [startup]

I have checked to see if access.xml and artifactory.xml is present in $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost. I have the files with right permissions. I checked the firewall and all required ports are open.

reference:

1. https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-to-resolve-a-service-registry-ping-failed-error-after-an-artifactory-upgrade/how-to-resolve-a-service-registry-ping-failed-error-after-an-artifactory-upgrade
2. https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-network-ports

Comment: It usually means that Access or the Router services are down and therefore the ping from RT doesn't work.
Do you see any different errors on the access-service.log or the router-service.log?

Comment: @shaibz Thank you for your response. I see the following in access-service.log

=====================================================

2023-12-12T04:56:34.142Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [d9a663f13918877a] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 140 Elapsed 1.17 minutes failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again